# Passing multiple columns to UDF in Scala Spark as Seq/Array

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a question - how can I get this to work?

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val peopleRDD: RDD[Person] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("Jacek", 10), 
                               Person("Femi", 11), Person("Lara",8)))
val people = peopleRDD.toDS
val concatUdf = udf { (rowCols: Seq[Any]) => rowCols.mkString}
```

I don't want to pass a Row to the udf as I would like to call the udf as part of a non-Spark framework (mleap)

```
 val resDf = people.select(col("*"),concatUdf(struct("name","age")))
```

But when I do

```
 resDf.show()
```

I get the following error:

```
   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
   Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: 
     (struct<name:string,age:int>) => string)
   at   

   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.\
   GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.\
   project_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
   ....


  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema\
   cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
   at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:24)

   ...
```

Can someone explain how I can get this to work without having to send a Row to the UDF ?

Answer (score 0):

The following would pass multiple columns:

```
val resDf = people.select(col("*"),concatUdf(array("name","age")))
```

On a different note, You should using `.withColumn()` to create a new columns. Nevertheless `.select()` works too, but alias name need to be specified manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work somewhat by using this code:

```
 import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
 case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
 val peopleRDD: RDD[Person] = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("Jack", 10), 
                                                 Person("Remi", 11), 
                                                 Person("Lola", 8)))
 val people = peopleRDD.toDS
 def concatModel(params: Map[String, Any])={params("name") + 
                               params("age").toString()}
 val concatUdf = udf { (name: String, age: Int) => 
               concatModel(Map("name"->name, "age"->age))}
 val resDf= people.withColumn("data",
                           concatUdf(col("name"),col("age")))
 resDf.show()
```